# How do I get the m/z = 101 peak for 3-methylbutyl propanoate?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

([reference](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/landingpage?spcode=MS-NW-5740), second source [here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Isoamyl-propionate#section=Information-Sources))

I've found the bigger peaks like m/z = 57, and 70 but how do I get 101? I've tried everything I could think of, like inductive cleavage or McLafferty rearrangement. Since it's 101, using rule of 13 I get the most likely formula to be C5H9O2. But the alcohol-chain has 11 hydrogens, how do I take 2 hydrogens away and end up with 5 carbons?

Comment: M/z=101 is ~ 4 times less intense than m/z=43. Minor fragmentation between C2-C3 of the alcohol moiety gives these two cations CH3CH2CO2CH2CH2+ (101) and CH3CHCH3+ (43).

Comment: I should add that m/z=43 is more intense because it is a secondary cation rather than primary (m/z=101).